# Google Cloud SQL On Demand activation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I would like to use Google Cloud SQL with my application in App Maker that is used occasionally. So I need some pricing configuration that doesn't charge me 24/7. But I know that activation policy "On Demand" is not available in Second Generation of Cloud SQL. Is there any other way (some replacement) how to reduce the costs for App Maker applications - i.e. I want to be charged only if application is used and active.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you have two options:

- Manually stop/start the Cloud SQL instance when you want it to be serving/stopped
- Start/stop the instance when you want it to be serving/stopped with some scripted way ([a Cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron), for example)

There's also this [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69109113) in Google's Issue Tracker where a somewhat "on demand" option for Cloud SQL is being requested. You can follow the development there and add your comments or even create your own Feature Request for the Cloud SQL team to see and consider.